# Geopandas spatial join giving empty result

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join

I have two GeoDataframes : one has polygons, the other points.

```
df_points

x   y   z   geometry
0   1844035.96  5172079.80  172.74  POINT (1844035.960 5172079.800)
1   1844036.48  5172079.77  172.78  POINT (1844036.480 5172079.770)
2   1844036.94  5172079.74  172.93  POINT (1844036.940 5172079.740)
3   1844037.39  5172079.71  173.12  POINT (1844037.390 5172079.710)
4   1844037.88  5172079.68  173.18  POINT (1844037.880 5172079.680)
... ... ... ... ...
```

```
df_poly

    commune name    type    created updated geometry
0   69001   None    01  2003-12-12  2018-04-23  POLYGON ((1810135.020 5183850.517, 1810133.653...
1   69001   None    01  2003-12-12  2018-04-23  POLYGON ((1810337.438 5183826.746, 1810328.829...
2   69001   None    01  2003-12-31  2018-04-23  POLYGON ((1810620.774 5183915.964, 1810632.762...
3   69001   None    01  2003-12-12  2018-04-23  POLYGON ((1809572.945 5184941.853, 1809580.233...
4   69001   None    01  2003-12-12  2018-04-23  POLYGON ((1809564.855 5184931.139, 1809558.822...
... ... ... ... ...
```

Both are in CRS EPSG:3946.

To get the points contained in each polygon, I do

```
gpd.sjoin(df_points, df_poly, op = 'within')
```

Initially, the above function returned an empty dataframe, but that's because I had an issue in my polygon dataset that resulted in no mapping.
Consequently, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the `how` parameter which is `"inner"` by default (see docu [here](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html)). `"inner"` keeps only the left geometries once the condition (`"within"`) is `True` for both datasets which is not the case (the polygons are not within the points).

Example code (returning point geometries within polygons):

```
gpd.sjoin(df_points, df_poly, how = 'left', op = 'within')
```